# Why the sum of the responses of s and s increase with 20dB per decade or 40dB per decade?

Tags: bode-plot

I am not sure by how much will the response of the function H(s) = s^2 increase?

Comment: The amplitude frequency response of the transfer function, \$H(s)=s^2\$, increases at 40 dB/decade.

Comment: @Chu thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If s = 1 and then changes to 10, the square of s changes from 1 to 100. So for a change in s of 10 (1 to 10 or a decade), the amplitude changes by 100.

Now convert 100 to decibels by taking the log and multiplying by 20. That decibel change is 40 dB in one decade.